# Include TikZ code in bookdown figure environment

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown, tikzdevice

I'd like to add a TikZ figure to a `bookdown` document in order to include some fancy graphics.

My primary output format is LaTeX which means that I could essentially just include the TikZ graphics verbatim in the Rmarkdown file and it would render fine. However, two problems are haunting me:

- I'd like for the TikZ graphics to be part of a figure environment (for the numbering, caption etc).
- I'd like to be able to render the same code to both PDF (LaTeX) and Gitbook (HTML).

Right now I have the following chunk which nicely produces the relevant graph as a figure when I render to pdf.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, engine='tikz', out.width='90%', fig.ext='pdf', fig.cap='Some caption.'}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
\draw [fill=gray!30,very thick] (0,-1) rectangle (5,1);
\draw [very thick] (5, 0) -- (13,0);
\node [below] at (2,-1) {\large Hello};
\node [below, align=center] at (0,-1) {\large Two\\ lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

However, there are two problems with the code:

1. I do not get any output when rendering to gitbook (using `knitr` and `bookdown`). I do get the figure caption, however, and if I render to `html_document` then it works too and I can see the graph.
2. For PDF the text is rendered using the computer modern font. I'd really like to change this, and the main font in the LaTeX document has already been set to something else. However, because the code is rendered locally by the TikZ engine and then inserted, it is not part of the full LaTeX document. Can I add some LaTeX options, packages etc. that are included by the TikZ engine *before* the code is rendered?

If there are other ways to include the TikZ code as part of a figure environment then I'd be happy to know.

**Update:** I guess the second point could be fixed by setting `engine.opts = list(template = "latex/tikz2pdf.tex")` where the necessary setup for LaTeX is included in the `tikz2pdf.tex` file. That file is read using LaTeX but I'd like to use `xelatex` to parse the file since I'm using the `fontspec` LaTex package. Can that be changed anyway?

Comment: All I can say is that this could be possible, but I don't have time to investigate it. You have to look really, really deep into knitr's source code to figure it out (it may require some changes in knitr).

Comment: pandoc filters might help http://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#building-images-with-tikz

Answer (score 11):

I think I found an answer to both of my questions. It did take - as Yihui pointed out - quite some time. I'm including the answer here in case someone else turns out to need this (or myself at a later point).

**Re 1) Render TikZ code to both pdf and gitbook**

This turned out to be easier than I anticipated. Setting the argument `fig.ext=if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) 'pdf' else 'png'` as part of the chunk arguments helps this along. If I'm *not* knitting to PDF then imagemagick or some other software automatically converts it to PNG.

**Re 2) Modifying the font**

As listed in my updated question this can be set by tweaking the file `tikz2pdf.tex` that is part of knitr. A copy of it is included below so you don't have to search for it yourself. Setting the chunk argument `engine.opts = list(template = "latex/tikz2pdf.tex")` enables you to put any desired fonts, LaTeX packages etc in preamble before the TikZ code is rendered.

Looking through the `knitr` code, you can see that `texi2dvi` is used to parse the `tikz2pdf.tex` file with the TikZ code inserted. `texi2dvi` calls `pdflatex` which messes things up in case you need to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to include TrueType fonts using `fontspec`.

I'm sure it would be possible to fix that somehow in the `texi2dvi` code but a much simpler solution (at least for me) was to change the environment. If I set the two environmental variable *before* starting R and rendering the book then xelatex is automatically used for compiling all the code. In my bash terminal this is done using

```
export LATEX="xelatex"
export PDFLATEX="xelatex"
```

Voila!

The chunk becomes

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, engine='tikz', out.width='90%', fig.ext=if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) 'pdf' else 'png', fig.cap='Some caption.', engine.opts = list(template = "latex/tikz2pdf.tex")
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
\draw [fill=gray!30,very thick] (0,-1) rectangle (5,1);
\draw [very thick] (5, 0) -- (13,0);
\node [below] at (2,-1) {\large Hello};
\node [below, align=center] at (0,-1) {\large Two\\ lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

and `tikz2pdf.tex` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\include{preview}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
%% INSERT YOUR OWN CODE HERE 
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
%% TIKZ_CODE %%
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

I'm still surprised at the whole flexibility of `knitr` and related packages. Nice work Yihui!

Comment: I had the install the `texinfo` and `imagemagick` packages on ubuntu but it works! Thanks!

Comment: Concerning 2) you might also look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143900/8416610

Comment: Thanks for this, I am using this solution, however I noticed that the .png does not come out so well - some (straight) lines are thicker than others.

Comment: Could you produce an MWE where it happens so we can look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems compiling plots with The `pgfplots`  and `bookdown`. Using `engine='tikz'`,  gave the error message: 'axis environment does not exist'. I fixed it by changing `\usepackage{tikz}` to `\usepackage{pgfplots}` in the `tikz2pdf.tex` file and using `engine.opts = list(template ="Tikz2pdf.tex")` as suggested.