# Using tikz graphdrawing library within RMarkdown ... Need to use lualatex engine, but can't get it to work

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, tikz, tikzdevice

I have the following code in an `rmd` file which leverages `tikz` for diagrams:

````
---
title: "TestNonTufteLua"
author: "Me"
output:
  pdf_document :
    latex_engine: lualatex
---

Prove tikz works:
```{r tikTest1, engine = "tikz"}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[ellipse, draw=black, align = center] (Data) {Data $y_{n}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then, when you set `eval = TRUE` in the below code, it will not work. 
```{r tikTest2, eval = FALSE, engine = "tikz"}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\tikz [gr/.style={gray!50}, font=\bfseries]
\graph [layered layout] {
    % A and F are horizontally aligned if you also set weight=0.5 for A -- C.
    A -- [minimum layers=2] C -- F,
    { [nodes=gr, edges=gr] A -- B -- { E, D -- F } }
};
```
````

When changing to `eval=TRUE` in the second chunk, I get the following
error:

> Quitting from lines 24-29 (testNonTufteLua.Rmd)  Error: running
>   'texi2dvi' on '.\tikz36747a021b22.tex' failed
>
> LaTeX errors: rarygraphdrawing.code.tex:22: Package pgf Error: You
>   need to run LuaTeX to use  the graph drawing library.

This error occurs when using the `knit` button from RStudio or using `render("testNonTufteLua.Rmd", output_format = pdf_document(keep_tex = TRUE, latex_engine = "lualatex")`.  I have also experimented with setting `options(tikzDefaultEngine = "luatex")` to get `tikzDevice` to handle it properly, but it still does not work.  I just can't seem to get the `graphdrawing` library to work even though the `tikz-shapes` library can be loaded and also that the rest of the document seems to be compiled with `lualatex`.  Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2):

Update: Meanwhile `knitr` no longer uses `tools::texi2dvi` but `tinytex::latexmk`. One therefore has to use `options(tinytex.engine = 'lualatex')` in a set-up chunk.

---

This is rather tricky, since you are not using `tikzDevice` but the `tikz` engine, which uses `tools::texi2dvi` to convert to PDF. You can change this using `options(texi2dvi = "lualatex")`. However, the default template does not work with LuaLaTeX. I have therefore created a modified template:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[luatex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
%% TIKZ_CODE %%
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

And specify that file with `engine.opts = list(template = "tikz2pdf.tex")`. Putting it all together here my working file:

````
---
title: "TestNonTufteLua"
author: "Me"
output:
  pdf_document :
    latex_engine: lualatex
---

```{r}
options(texi2dvi = "lualatex")
```

```{r tikTest2, eval = TRUE, engine = "tikz", engine.opts = list(template = "tikz2pdf.tex")}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\tikz [gr/.style={gray!50}, font=\bfseries]
\graph [layered layout] {
    % A and F are horizontally aligned if you also set weight=0.5 for A -- C.
    A -- [minimum layers=2] C -- F,
    { [nodes=gr, edges=gr] A -- B -- { E, D -- F } }
};
```
````

Result:

[image]

References:

- [how to set engine options](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/058-engine-tikz.md)
- [preview and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333826/is-there-a-defect-in-the-preview-package-of-tex-live)
- [knitr using texi2pdf](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/4b64980ac3fcd1170112d73b52c43517a02dede9/R/engine.R#L290)

Answer (score 0):

A small running variation of the example above is the following using `tinytex`.

````
    ---
    title: "lualatex. Using `tinytex.engine`"
    output:
      html_document:
        df_print: paged
      pdf_document:
        latex_engine: lualatex
    ---

   ## Latex engines
   By default, PDF documents are rendered using `pdflatex`. You can specify an
   alternate engine using the `latex_engine` option. Available engines 
   are `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, and `lualatex.` 

    ```{r setup}
    options(tinytex.engine = "lualatex")
    ```

    ```{r tikzLua, eval = TRUE, engine = "tikz", engine.opts = list(template =  "tikz2pdf.tex")}
    \usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
    \usegdlibrary{layered}

   \tikz [gr/.style={gray!50}, font=\bfseries]
   \graph [layered layout] {
    % A and F are horizontally aligned if you also set weight=0.5 for A -- C.
    A -- [minimum layers=2] C -- F,
    { [nodes=gr, edges=gr] A -- B -- { E, D -- F } }
    };
    ```
````

After an update in `knitr` the example above stopped running.