# How to force Tikz in RMarkdown document to show cyrillic text?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, tikz

Below is my experimental RMarkdown document (named *tikz-cyrillic.Rmd*):

````
---
title: "TikZ cyrillic test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    dev: tikz
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r,engine='tikz', fig.ext = if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) 'pdf' else 'svg'}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node
(x) {Hello World!}
(3,1) node[circle,draw](y) {$\int_1^2 x \mathrm d x$};
\draw[->,blue]
(x) -- (y);
\draw[->,red]
(x) -| node[near start,below] {мир!} (y);
\draw[->,orange] (x) .. controls +(up:1cm) and +(left:1cm) .. node[above,sloped] {Привет} (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

It is based on example [from 17.11 of pgfmanual.pdf](http://ctan.altspu.ru/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Gummi using *TeXLive with XeTeX* with simple preamble

```
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman}
```

gives me the following output:

[image: Gummi output]

You can test it [in OverLeaf](https://www.overleaf.com/18355262mgjnkvvhvnby).

But in RStudio I can't understand where should I enter preamble for TikZ device, so I have wrong output (HTML as example):

[image: RStudio HTML-output]

What should I change in RMarkdown document to get correct output in TikZ diagram?

I need the same image appearance for HTML, PDF and Word document (docx).

Note: I'm using Gummi and RStudio 1.1.456 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with TeXLive 2015 if it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuring the knitr engine is possible, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143900/8416610 for references. Your case is different, since you need both PDF and SVG output. Since SVG output uses DVI, we cannot use `xelatex` for processing the `tikz` graphic. Instead we have to setup standard `latex` to output Cyrillic:

````
---
title: "TikZ cyrillic test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document: default
mainfont: Liberation Serif
monofont: Liberation Mono
---

```{r,engine='tikz', fig.ext = if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) 'pdf' else 'svg', engine.opts = list(template = "tikz2pdf-cyr.tex")}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node
(x) {Hello World!}
(3,1) node[circle,draw](y) {$\int_1^2 x \mathrm d x$};
\draw[->,blue]
(x) -- (y);
\draw[->,red]
(x) -| node[near start,below] {мир!} (y);
\draw[->,orange] (x) .. controls +(up:1cm) and +(left:1cm) .. node[above,sloped] {Привет} (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

With `tikz2pdf-cyr.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
%% TIKZ_CODE %%
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Note that here different fonts are used for the image and the main text. At the moment I cannot upload any screen shots ...

Comment: Thank you very much! PDF output works as expected. But for HTML (`html_document`) and DOC (`word_document`) I get errors: *Quitting from lines 18-28 (tikz-cyrillic.Rmd) 
Error in engine(options) : 
  Failed to compile tikz; check the template: tikz2pdf-cyr.tex
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir -> engine
Execution halted*. Could you please fix them? And then I mark problem as solved :)

Comment: Thank you again, @RalfStubner ! Now it is working as I expect.