# Tikzpictures not rendering in gitbook, even though they appear in pdf_book

Tags: r, latex, knitr, bookdown, tikz

I'm using `bookdown` to type up my notes from some of my math courses. I want to insert tikzpictures into my book, and even though they render perfectly when using `render_book("index.Rmd", "pdf_book")`, they do not appear at all, on any browser (I've tried Chrome, Firefox, and even Internet Explorer) when I use `render_book("index.Rmd", "gitbook")`. Likewise when using `preview_chapter` instead of `render_book`.

Here is the code that can be used to render my Tikz image:

```
\def\firstcircle{(0:-0.5cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:0.4cm) circle (0.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \secondcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[outline] \firstcircle node {$B$};
    \draw[outline] \secondcircle node {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$A$ as a subset of $B$}
\end{figure}
```

When I use `pdf_book` it's beautiful. If I use `gitbook` it just does not appear. I've tried to do something similar as what's described in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358934/include-tikz-code-in-bookdown-figure-environment) i.e. using the same chunk but replacing that code with my code (though I did center mine) like so:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, engine='tikz', out.width='90%', fig.ext='pdf', fig.align='center', fig.cap='Some caption.'}
\def\firstcircle{(0:-0.5cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:0.4cm) circle (0.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \secondcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[outline] \firstcircle node {$B$};
    \draw[outline] \secondcircle node {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

when I do this, again it renders beautifully in `pdfbook` and actually I get further in `gitbook` (the figure caption appears and a "broken image link" symbol appears, I've tried across browsers, as mentioned) but still no image.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `fig.ext='pdf'` you are creating a PDF file, that your browser cannot include. Instead, you can use something like `fig.ext=if(knitr:::is_latex_output()) 'pdf' else 'png'` to use PDF output together with LaTeX and PNG output for all other cases. Alternatively, you could remove `fig.ext` completely and use the defaults. Given one of these changes, you example works for me with both HTML/Gitbook and PDF/LaTeX output.